# Views in Ruby on Rails, enabling submit_tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an html.erb file which includes the following

```
<%= submit_tag "Locate", :disabled => true %>
```

I also have `<%= text_field_tag  'locationPOS', "", :disabled => true  %>` which has its value updated when the user click on the google map present on the page (from a separate javascript file) by `locpos.value = place.address;`

I would like to enable the `submit_tag` only when there is text within the `'locationPOS'` `text_field_tag`.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your view:

```
<%=text_field_tag 'locationPOS', "", :disabled => true, 
:onchange => "check_value(this.value);" %>
```

and

```
<%= submit_tag "Locate", :disabled => true, :id => "my_submit_button" %>
```

Add javascript function to your view similar to this:

```
function check_value(val)
{
  if(val.length > 0)
  {
    document.getElementById("my_submit_button").disabled=false;
  }
}
```

I am sure some debugging of above code will be necessary. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this helped me notice that all i needed to add was :id =>"my_submit_button" after all in my previous code which made it work like a charm. thanks!!